# Face detector program in C via arrays

Tags: c, arrays

So I need to make a "face detector" program in C. Basically I need to input the number of "face detections", resolution height and width (max 120), and the coordinates of the "face". Then the input is three h*w arrays which serve as RGB values.

The output of the program should be the same RGB values from the input, but with a green rectangle connecting the coordinates (thus highlighting the face on the picture), and the alpha values in the rectangle being 255 (the rest being alpha=127).

The issue I have is that the outputs are completely wrong. The first test case, which is a 5x5 black square with false coordinates, works fine. But the other test cases are actual pictures with 100x80 resolution. In those cases instead of a green rectangle, its random green lines and dots around the picture. The alpha value is simmilarly wrong, where its randomly 127 and randomly 255. I've tried rewriting my code several times, but the result is the same every time, just random values for alpha and G.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 120

int main() {
FILE* fin = fopen("input.txt", "r");
FILE* fout = fopen("output.txt", "w");

int R[MAX][MAX], G[MAX][MAX], B[MAX][MAX], x1[MAX], y1[MAX], x2[MAX], 
y2[MAX], A[MAX][MAX];
int h, w, n, i, j, k;

fscanf(fin, "%d %d %d", &n, &h, &w);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fscanf(fin, "%d %d %d %d", &x1[i], &y1[i], &x2[i], &y2[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        fscanf(fin, "%d ", &R[i][j]);
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        fscanf(fin, "%d ", &G[i][j]);
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        fscanf(fin, "%d ", &B[i][j]);
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        A[i][j] = 127;
    }
}
for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for (i = x1[k]; i <= x2[k]; ++i) {
        G[i][y1[k]] = 255; 
        G[i][y2[k]] = 255;  
        A[i][y1[k]] = 255;
        A[i][y2[k]] = 255;
        R[i][y1[k]] = 0;
        R[i][y2[k]] = 0;
        B[i][y1[k]] = 0;
        B[i][y2[k]] = 0;
    }
    for (j = y1[k]; j <= y2[k]; ++j) {
        G[x1[k]][j] = 255;
        G[x2[k]][j] = 255; 
        A[x1[k]][j] = 255;
        A[x2[k]][j] = 255;
        R[x1[k]][j] = 0;
        R[x2[k]][j] = 0;
        B[x1[k]][j] = 0;
        B[x2[k]][j] = 0;
    }
}
for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for (i = x1[k] + 1; i <= x2[k] - 1; i++) {
        for (j = y1[k] + 1; j <= y2[k] - 1; j++) {
            A[i][j] = 255;
        }
    }
}
fprintf(fout, "/image %d %d RGBA\n", h, w);
for (i = 0; i < w; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        fprintf(fout, "%d %d %d %d ", R[i][j], G[i][j], B[i][j], A[i][j]);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: do your `fopen`s succeed? Are your `n, h, w` inputs `<= MAX`? Run in a debugger, it will tell you where it's crashing and examining the variables may tell you why. I'd guess out of bounds somewhere.

Comment: To clarify, it does give out values to the output.txt. But the values are completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the logic you have so I would step through your solution with testcases like yano suggested to see if you are having issues reading things in.

You do make the mistake of not setting the R and B values to 0 when you set the G value to 255 for the rectangle.

Next I would do two things: sanitize your inputs and simplify your loops.

For sanitizing your inputs just make sure that your with, height, and number of faces are less than your max. The coordinates you receive for each face rectangle should all be less than w and h, but greater than 0. Also double check that your face rectangles are always in the format of: [bottom-left x val, bottom-left y val, top-right x val, top-right y val] like you assume when you do all of these calculations. If there were an input problem here, that would be my guess at the most likely to cause hidden issues.

You can simplify your loops to avoid touching anything outside of your rectangles when coloring the Alpha and Green.

For the Green values, just loop over the sides. Loop through all of the faces (n) like you are doing, but just do:

```
for (i = x1[n]; i <= x2[n]; ++i) { G[i][y1[n]] = 255; G[i][y2[n]] = 255; // Also set A to 255 as well as R and B to 0 here }
for (j = y1[n]; j <= y2[n]; ++j) { G[x1[n]][j] = 255; G[x2[n]][j] = 255; // Also set A to 255 as well as R and B to 0 here }
```

And then cover the Alpha values inside the rectangle by looping from x1[n] + 1 to x2[n] - 1 and y1[n] + 1 to y2[n] - 1. This will not only make your program quicker, but should stop any erroneous green or alpha values to show up anywhere outside of your given points.

After fixing those things it should be much easier to debug and see where errors are when you get unexpected behavior.

Edit: I missed a case for input sanitation.

Comment: I tried your advice, and while the results are a BIT better, it still isn't even close. The alpha values are all over the place (basically a few lines of pixels are alpha 127, then a few are 255), and even the green rectangle isn't done right for god knows what reason. I'd love to post a test case so you could see for yourself, but I can't for privacy reasons.